# Can't setup Qt Quick application with Qt 5.14

Tags: qt, qt5, version, qt-creator, qt-quick

I upgraded my Qt Creator to version 11, but now I can't set up any Qt Quick projects since the wizard to set it up allows minimum Qt version 6.2, 6.4 or 6.6.

Is it not possible to set up a Qt Quick application in Qt Creator 11 with Qt 5.14.*?

What I already tried:

- Installed Qt Creator 11.
- Added Qt 5.14 qmake to dev kit.
- Linking Qt version with Qt Creator did not work since I can't add the Qt folder under `C://QT/QT514` to the File grabber, so I don´t really know what to add there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select "[***Qt Quick Application (compat)***](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-projects.html#qt-quick-applications)" from Qt Creator's *New Project Wizard*.

See the below screenshot:

[image: "Qt Quick Application (compat)" option highlighted with a red rectangle in the New Project Wizard in Qt Creator]